# Как вычислить координаты дула ствола

Tags: lua, геометрия, координаты, love2d

Доброго времени суток! Есть спрайт (без треугольника):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Точка `A` имеет координаты (`Actor.x`;`Actor.y`).

```
Длина AB = 96
Длина BC = 86
Длина AC = 42

Все вычисления примерные, производились линейкой в фотошопе.
```

Спрайт всегда направлен на указатель мыши, угол поворота (в радианах) храниться в переменной `Actor.direction`. Спрайт рисуется в размере `0.3` от исходного изображения.

Все пули направлены туда же, куда и спрайт игрока. Создаваться они должны в точке `B`. Как рассчитать координаты точки `B` при **любом** угле поворота?

**UPD**

Если создавать пули в координатах

```
Actor.x + 96 * math.cos(Actor.direction) * 0.3 (учитывая масштаб)
Actor.y + 96 * math.sin(Actor.direction) * 0.3 (учитывая масштаб)
```

Получается вот что:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проэкция, всегда проэкция. `x = Ax + AB*cos(alpha) , y = Ay + AB*sin(alpha) ` всё. С масштабом как-то сами уже.

Comment: @nick_n_a, в качестве `alpha` использовать `Actor.direction`?

Comment: Да. `Actor.direction`

Comment: @nick_n_a, похоже проекция не всегда проекция :) (обновил вопрос)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На английском SO дали [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330819/how-to-calculate-coordinates-of-the-gunpoint):

```
cs = math.cos(Actor.direction)
sn = math.sin(Actor.direction)
```

Точка `B` будет смещена от `A` на `dx` и `dy`:

```
dx = - 42 * sn + 86 * cs
dy = 42 * cs + 86 * sn
```

С учетом масштабирования:

```
Bullet.x = Actor.x + (-42 * sn + 86 * cs) * 0.3
Bullet.y = Actor.y + (42 * cs + 86 * sn) * 0.3
```